# Why can't I create an array as a column in a table in Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, arrays, rails-migrations

Why can't I do something like this:

```
class CreateModels < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def self.up
    create_table :fruit do |t|
      t.array :apples
    end
  end
end
```

Is there some other way to make an array ("apples) be an attribute of an instance of the Fruit class?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check out the [Rails guide on associations](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html) (pay particular attention to has_many).

You can use any column type supported by your database (use `t.column` instead of `t.type`), although if portability across DBs is a concern, I believe it's recommended to stick to the types explicitly supported by activerecord.

It seems kind of funny for fruit to have_many apples, but maybe that is just an example? (I would expect apples to be a subclass of fruit).

Comment: Careful, SQL99 includes arrays but I don't know how broadly supported they are (PostgreSQL supports them at least).

Comment: @mu is too short: thanks, i wasn't aware of the array support in SQL99.  If i'm reading the spec right they are limited to the builtin datatypes, so you still wouldn't be able to get away with an array of apples.

Comment: But you would be able to get away with an array of apple IDs. I don't know how widely supported arrays are, SQL99 is only 12 years old after all and database vendors aren't that quick at moving towards portability and standards based systems :)

Comment: @mu is too short: good point, I changed my answer accordingly.

Comment: Thanks Cam. "Apple" and "fruit" were random words in my example.

Answer (score 25):

In Rails 4 and using PostgreSQL you can actually use an array type in the DB:

Migration:

```
class CreateSomething < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    create_table :something do |t|
      t.string :some_array, array: true, default: []
      t.timestamps
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: It is better to use type `text` in your array column instead of string, since by default string will be evaluated as varchar in Postgres and text will be evaluated as text field.

:string -> VARCHAR -> :limit => 1 to 255 (default = 255)  

:text   -> TINYTEXT, TEXT, MEDIUMTEXT, or LONGTEXT2 -> :limit => 1 to 4294967296 (default = 65536)

Answer (score 2):

You may use [serialize](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Base.html#method-c-serialize). But if an Apple is going to be an AR object, use [associations](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html).