# Rails, association ids in one single cell with commas (not many rows in another table)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, activerecord, rails-activerecord

I'm following this great cast:

http://railscasts.com/episodes/258-token-fields-revised

My database is **Postgres**.

This schema:

**author.rb**

```
class Author < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :name
  has_many :authorships
  has_many :books, through: :authorships

  def self.tokens(query)
    authors = where("name like ?", "%#{query}%")
    if authors.empty?
      [{id: "<<<#{query}>>>", name: "New: \"#{query}\""}]
    else
      authors
    end
  end

  def self.ids_from_tokens(tokens)
    tokens.gsub!(/<<<(.+?)>>>/) { create!(name: $1).id }
    tokens.split(',')
  end
end
```

**authorship.rb**

```
class Authorship < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :book
  belongs_to :author
end
```

**book.rb**

```
class Book < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :name, :author_tokens
  has_many :authorships
  has_many :authors, through: :authorships
  attr_reader :author_tokens

  def author_tokens=(tokens)
    self.author_ids = Author.ids_from_tokens(tokens)
  end
end
```

But I don't want to create the **"authorship"** table because of many rows! I want simply add in the book's table a column (string) with the author's ids, like this:

**Books table**:

```
    id    |    name    |    author_ids    
-------------------------------------------
     1    |   Book A   |  15,12,16,19,2
     2    |   Book B   |  1,2,5,44,159,3
```

Is this possible?

Comment: what is the database client you are running ?

Comment: Postgresql. Is this important? Can i use the specific array feature of postgre?

Comment: why do you want to avoid the `Authorship` table? It is very handy to have - and a table is meant to have many rows. Databases are able to cope with *millions* of entries.

Comment: Because I think the array in cell is useful, instead an heavy table with thousand rows! I'm wrong?

Comment: It is surely possible, but not *useful* nor *flexible*. Say you want to add an attribute like an author being a co author for a book. There is no way to add this in the cell.

Comment: @TheChamp, I don't understand your example.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6603743/why-cant-i-create-an-array-as-a-column-in-a-table-in-rails

Comment: @JohnSam Yes, you can use Postgresql's Array datatype for this.. That's why I asked..

Comment: If you set up a relationship between a book and an author via the array, you are limited *solely* to the connection. If you set up a relational table, you can further describe the connection lateron. You'll have to take my word for it that it's more flexible. The number of rows aren't an issue here, so unless you have other issues I'd go with the more flexible solution.